# Can't find folder in filesystem on Juypter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, filesystems, pytorch

I have downloaded files using the following function [download_from_url](https://pytorch.org/text/utils.html#download-from-url) and it seems to download them and put them into a folder called .data however I can't seem to find the folder in the file system. Everything works fine otherwise and the files seem to exist but I can't see them.

Any ideas where they are?

(I tried printing out the path and I got the following: "./.data/yelp_review_polarity_csv/train.csv" but I still can't find that anywhere.)

Comment: Are you running it on your own device or google collab? Download directory does exist somewhere it may be in your google drive. otherwise, you can also set root for the files to be downloaded and placed in a specific path

Comment: I'm running this on Paperspace (similar to collab)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `os.getcwd` to get the current working directory and `os.chdir` if you want to move to a new directory.

Before downloading your file, you should change your working directory to insure where your data are:

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/the/dir/of/your/choice')
[... your downloading code ...]
```

Comment: I know how to put it in a findable directory in the future, but I'm still trying to find these files saved in the past

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

"./.data/yelp_review_polarity_csv/train.csv"

is a hidden directory (e.g. ".data")

So I was able to find it with: ls -a